# How to use TCPDF library with Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to include TCPDF library in Zend2. but i am not able to get success. Please and any one give the solution to fix this issue.

Thanks
Siva

Comment: Would you like to include the exact problem you are facing and the approach you already tried.  This will help the community help you.  With the information you give,  it is impossible to help you as there can be a thousand reasons for this.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Add the line below into `composer.json` file's `require` section in your project root:

```
"require": {
    "php"                         : ">=5.4",
    "zendframework/zendframework" : "2.3.1",
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf"            : "dev-master" <<<-- this line --
},
```

Open your terminal (command line) and type:

```
cd /path/to/your/project/root
php composer.phar selfupdate
php composer.phar update
```

And anywhere in your app:

```
$pdf = new \TCPDF();
```

Thats it.

Comment: updated the directory using composer, but new tcpdf() is not working
error saying tcpdf not found

Answer (score 0):

add the  **"tecnickcom/tcpdf"            : "dev-master"** 
in the composer.json

```
  "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^0.7 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "^3.3",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf"            : "dev-master"
    },
```

run the **composer update** in the root of your project directory

add the **use \TCPDF;** top of your controller file

paste the following code in your function

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->AddPage();
$html ="<style>
th{border:0.5px solid #C0C0C0;background-color:rgb(44,126,193); font-size: 9pt;text-align: center;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;}
td{ vertical-align: middle;padding-top:5px;border:0.5px solid #C0C0C0;padding:5pt;color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-size: 8pt;text-align: center;}
</style>
<table>
<thead>
<tr nobr=”true”><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr nobr=”true”>
<td>1</td>
<td>Senta</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>";

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```